# guild.members.get() from variable/string returns undefined

Tags: discord.js

I'm having a bit of trouble getting a GuildMember from a variable/ID.
When I run this:

```
tempUserId = "'" + groupColor[c].toString() + "'";
console.log(tempUserId);

let tempUser = msg.guild.members.get(tempUserId);
console.log(tempUser);
```

It logs as this:

```
'145571765605761025'
undefined
```

And that "undefined" is big trouble. If I instead run the code by typing in the ID myself, like this:

```
tempUserId = "'" + groupColor[c].toString() + "'";
console.log(tempUserId);

let tempUser = msg.guild.members.get('144832508180037632');
console.log(tempUser);
```

It works just fine and as expected.
Why doesn't my first example work? My thinking is that because the text inside the .get() parentheses is the same both times I should expect the same results? But maybe it has something to do with data-types, or different kind of variables?

UPDATE:
As it turns out, a good night's sleep is the best debugger. The ID inside the .get() parntheses is supposed to be a string. Thus converting groupColor[c] to a string is enough, no need to add the apostrophes. The new code looks like this:

```
let tempUser = msg.guild.members.get(groupColor[c].toString());
```

I wasn't any more complicated than that...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are over complicating things.  The single quotes around the user id in the second example are syntax denoting that it is a string rather than a number.  However in the first example you are converting (presumably) a number to a string and then trying to tack on quotes as well, this simply isn't necessary as it's already a string returned by the toString method, and instead your quotes are being treated literally.

`tempUserId = "'" + groupColor[c].toString() + "'";`

is effectively the same as saying

`tempUserId = '\'144832508180037632\'';`

Remove those extra quotes and see if that solves your problem.

`tempUserId = groupColor[c].toString()`

alternatively, skip the variable

`msg.guild.members.get(groupColor[c].toString())`

By the way, `undefined` means the get method found nothing, this is completely normal as what you were searching for couldn't possibly be there.  If you think there is a possibility a valid input might not be there, you should add some sort of conditional to check the result.

```js
let result = msg.guild.members.get(groupColor[c].toString());
if(result)
{
    // Do something with result
}
```

This is a good idea unless you KNOW the user id is good.  If it's possible the user left the guild, it will return undefined normally.

Comment: Yeah, I know I’m overcomplicating it. I tried just using groupColor[c] without converting it to a string or adding the apostrophes, which I thought would have worked, but it didnt...  The ID is mine, and Im definitely connected to the guild, as Im the one typing the command.

Comment: @MechaFlex Are you saying you tried it and it worked, or you tried it before and it did not?  If not, I'd need to see more about how groupColor is created to know what is going on.

Comment: I tried groupColor[c] first before adding any tostring conversions or apostrophes, when that didnt work I tried to reeeeeally make sure I was inputting the same thing  in the .get() as on the working example where I typed the ID myself. To make them the exact same I added the tostring and apostrophes. A bad solution, but I see no reason why it wouldnt work unless it has something to do with the variable-type.

Comment: I can only make assumptions as to what is in the array.  I would edit your original post to add the area of the code where this array gets populated.  If you can, use a stepper to step through the code line by line and watch the contents of the array to see if it looks valid.  Ideally you want to create a minimal reproducible example to post here
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I will do that tomorrow! Thanks a lot so far!

Comment: Check update, I solved it. This was really a simple problem with a simple answer. Thanks anyway!